# Nuxt SSR application can not find some files generated by pipeline

Tags: nuxt.js, pipeline, server-side-rendering, buddy.com

I have a Nuxt SSR app which want to deploy on server. My CI (Buddy) runs pipeline to do it by running bash commands. All of them runs without any error but at the end application can not find files in .nuxt directory. It throws an error 404 not found _nuxt/**46f6559.modern.js**
Everything looks ok except the file really does not exists on the server. I try it by command

```
sudo find .  -type f -name 46f6559.modern.js
```

to find it. It seems like main file link to old files which no longer exists in repository. But really dont know what is going on there. The build looks fresh and .nuxt folder is filled by build files.

This are the commands in pipeline which works fine.

```
yarn build
```

Then

```
if [ -d "builds/$BUDDY_EXECUTION_REVISION" ] && [ "$BUDDY_EXECUTION_REFRESH" = "true" ];
then
   echo "Removing: builds/$BUDDY_EXECUTION_REVISION"
   rm -rf builds/$BUDDY_EXECUTION_REVISION;
fi

if [ ! -d "builds/$BUDDY_EXECUTION_REVISION" ];
then
   echo "Creating: builds/$BUDDY_EXECUTION_REVISION"
   cp -dR deploy-cache builds/$BUDDY_EXECUTION_REVISION;
fi
```

Then

```
echo "Linking current to revision: $BUDDY_EXECUTION_REVISION"
rm -f current
ln -s builds/$BUDDY_EXECUTION_REVISION current
```

Then

```
pm2 startOrReload current/ecosystem.config.js --only Production
```

Everything ends up with success.
Does anybody know what could happened there? My be the last of the commands? If I run it on local machine everything works well. Thanks for any help.

Comment: When do you run that `find` command and also, from where do you take that `46f6559.modern.js` hash number? That one is supposed to be different each time (when you build it). If not sure what exists when, you should run a `ls` and check the files before your whole CI and after, just before it's done running.

Comment: I see 46f6559.modern.js in browser network log as 404. Then I tried to find it by find command in the server root folder. There is no file with this name. Basic sceleton of Nuxt app is working and then it try to load components but there are no files. It seems like some kind of cache....

Comment: If it's 404 in the network tab, it's not on the server (seems logic). Now the question is why you're loading such file from your client side code. The issue is probably from here. Messed up with the hashes during the build phase?

Comment: Ok I have it. The problem is in the last command `pm2 startOrReload current/ecosystem.config.js --only Production` There has to be Development instead of Production

Comment: What's the difference between the two options?

Comment: ecosystem.config.js contains two environments. Production and Development. There are some differencies between them.

Comment: Thanks for help. PS Still dont know why component does not react on Vuex store getter change. Newst problem is that Vuex does not update getter value althought is is pretty simple object nothing exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by using

```sh
pm2 startOrReload current/ecosystem.config.js --only Development
```

rather than

```sh
pm2 startOrReload current/ecosystem.config.js --only Production
```